# trying to hide textbox with radio button selection

Tags: javascript, html, .net, model-view-controller

I am trying to show the textbox everytime DOB or DOJ is selected in MVC. This is what I have so far. The text box is hidden but wont show up.

```
<script>
    $("#textbox").hide();
    $("input[name='radio']").on("change", function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "DOB") {
            $("#textbox").show();
        }
    });
</script>



    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Find">
            <div id="textbox"
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.input)<br />
            </div>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.radio, "ID")<aspan>ID</aspan><br />
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.radio, "FirstName")<aspan>First Name</aspan><br />
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.radio, "LastName")<aspan>Last Name</aspan><br />
            <div id="buttons">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.radio, "DOB")<aspan>DOB</aspan><br />

            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.radio, "DOJ")<aspan>DOJ</aspan><br />
            </div>           
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.radio, "Phone")<aspan>Phone</aspan><br />
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.radio, "Email")<aspan>Email</aspan><br />
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Find" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```